# How to determine if a contract is valid across multiple lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write some SQL for determining and grouping if a contract is valid across multiple different lines.

Here is the scenario, I have a table that stores contracts that are valid for 364 days. There is a line for the initial start of the contract, then a line for the renewal. When the contract is out dated or closed there is another line for the closure. There are 2 types of contracts that do not overlap. If the person goes to the other contract the old one is closed out. The contracts are not uniquely identified, but the people have unique IDs.

Below is what I have for looking at the data.

```
SELECT CA.ConDate, CA.IsCon, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 10 * CA.IsCon, CA.ConDate), CA.RenewalStatus, CA.PersonID
FROM dbo.ConActivity CA
WHERE CA.RenewalStatus IN ( 1, 2 )
      AND CA.PersonID = '254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B'
ORDER BY DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 10 * CA.IsCon, CA.ConDate)
```

This returns the following results:

```
ConDate                 IsCon  (No column name)         RenewalStatus   PersonID
2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 0      2018-01-12 00:00:00.000  1               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2018-03-30 00:00:00.000 0      2018-03-30 00:00:00.000  2               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2018-06-26 00:00:00.000 0      2018-06-26 00:00:00.000  1               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2018-07-26 00:00:00.000 0      2018-07-26 00:00:00.000  1               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2019-07-02 00:00:00.000 0      2019-07-02 00:00:00.000  1               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2019-10-29 00:00:00.000 0      2019-10-29 00:00:00.000  2               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2019-10-29 00:00:00.000 1      2019-10-29 00:00:00.010  1               254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
```

RenewalStatus: 1 = Renewed (or opened), 2 = Closed

As you can see from the data, the contract can be open then closed for a period (that's one time period), then opened and renewed a few times under the same contract type before being converted to the other type of contract (that's another time period), then a new one opened in the new contract type and remains open until there is a closed RwnewalStatus (= 2). The (No column name) is just me putting the lines in the correct order and a method I tried to use to determine the time frames.

I want a line per person per contract validity, in this case I would like to see:

```
ConDate                 IsCon  ConEndDate               PersonID
2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 0      2018-03-30 00:00:00.000  254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2018-06-26 00:00:00.000 0      2019-10-29 00:00:00.000  254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
2019-10-29 00:00:00.000 1      NULL                     254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B
```

How would you achieve this result?

Comment: Please tag your database and version

Comment: What is `IsCon`?

Comment: IsCon is just a bit for determining if it is a Early contract or a Late contract. (Hey, I didn't design the database or the program on top. I think it's terrible.)

Comment: Once you've determined which rows go with which contract, you can make life much easier by adding a Contracts table with an ID and Person. Then add a reference to Contracts to ConActivity and remove ConActivity.PersonID. Then your query is much simpler: `select ContractId, min(ConDate), max(ConDate) from ConActivity group by ContractId`

Comment: @Schwern I am struggling mainly here to figure out what rows go to which contract to be honest. Thanks for the idea of a side table. That will prove useful when I migrate this into Power BI.

Comment: Your data requires ordered comparison between lines. In my experience this was normally solved by Cursors. Cursors are absolutely terrible for query performance so I would avoid them at all costs. Not a recommended solution but its usable as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DBMS supports *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
with cte as 
 (
    SELECT CA.ConDate, CA.IsCon, 
       DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 10 * CA.IsCon, CA.ConDate) as col,
       CA.RenewalStatus, CA.PersonID,
       -- assign the same value to all rows of 1 followed by 2 using a Cumulative Sum
       sum(case when RenewalStatus = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
       over (partition by PersonID
             order by ConDate desc, RenewalStatus
             rows unbounded preceding) as grp
    FROM tab CA
    WHERE CA.RenewalStatus IN ( 1, 2 )
          AND CA.PersonID = '254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B'
 )
select min(ConDate), max(IsCon),
    case when max(RenewalStatus) = 2 then max(ConDate) end, PersonID
from cte
-- now aggregate over the person and the group's value
group by PersonId, grp
```

Comment: This solution works very nice as long as there aren't more than 1 time spans for one particular contract type. I had something similar at one point, but couldn't figure out how to make it work fully. When I implement this solution I only get 2 lines, where I would expect 3.

{StartDate IsCon EndDate PersonID}
{2018-06-26 00:00:00.000 1 2019-10-29 00:00:00.000 254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B}
{2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 0 2018-03-30 00:00:00.000 254915C5-2F30-40C9-B7E9-0239E6CBE27B}

Comment: I see, there's two rows with the same ConDate, you need to modify the order. I edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent work! Works like a charm. Thank you so much for the assistance!